# AndEngine for OpenGL for live wallpaper?

Tags: android, andengine, live-wallpaper

I'm considering using OpenGL for a live wallpaper that I'm creating. But I'm wondering if I should use any physics engine like AndEngine. Since I have a little bit of 3d animations (like a cube and image flipping) in it, should I be using AndEngine? I'm not really sure what it is capable of.

Comment: AndEngine is a 2D engine, so I'm not sure how the integration with your 3D effects would look like. Also, AndEngine is NOT a physics engine, it uses a Box2D extension for handling physics.

Comment: @JohnEye Okay, have you ever seen 3d effects being done while using AndEngine?

Comment: I've never seen 3D effects used in AndEngine

Comment: @MJ93 Thanks that's what I wanted to know